# What is the right path of my image on JLabel?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to show the text with image using hmtl tag on JLabel by using  Eclipse . The image didn't show. Would someone help me to solve the problem? Thank in advance.

The image file path: C:\Users\useName\Documents\Java Project\Samples\Reader\src\Reader\QuestionMark.gif
There is the code to set the text for JLabel:

```
    lblDate.setText("<html><table><tr><td style='width:10pt;'></td><td>Page 2 02/27/2015 10:40:13 AM</td></tr><tr><td style='width:10pt;'><img src='/src/Reader/QuestionMark.gif'></img></td><td>*Completed</td></tr></table></html>");
```

My project code:

```
 package pdfReader;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;     
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

 public class TestHTMLLabel extends JFrame  implements ActionListener {

private GridBagConstraints c;
private JLabel lblDate=null;    

public TestHTMLLabel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setTitle("Test HTMLLabel example");
    setSize(300, 200);        
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // set flow layout for the frame

     this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     JPanel pl=new JPanel( new GridBagLayout());    


    c = new GridBagConstraints();                     
    c.gridx=0;
     c.gridy=2;
     c.gridwidth=4;  //left hand size
     c.ipady=140; //make this component tall      
     c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
     pl.add(setPageDateLabel(), c);

     c.ipady=0;
            c.gridx=0;
            c.gridy=3;            
            c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            pl.add(setContent(), c);
     this.add(pl);
     this.setVisible(true);

}

  private JScrollPane setContent(){

        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane();           
        JTextArea t=new JTextArea(6,20);        
        t.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis scelerisque arcu. Aliquam eleifend, ex vel ullamcorper dignissim, leo nulla aliquet turpis, vel accumsan ex risus sed neque. Aliquam ornare ac nunc id posuere. Vivamus at tortor risus. Praesent quam arcu, varius sed porttitor sodales, sagittis id justo. Cras dictum sollicitudin sem, vitae feugiat eros. Aenean dictum lorem eros, vitae suscipit purus eleifend sit amet. Phasellus sodales metus quam, quis semper nunc vehicula et. Donec sollicitudin lacinia ipsum, ut hendrerit mauris tristique a. In fringilla, tellus elementum lacinia feugiat, lectus dolor tincidunt libero, sit amet blandit tellus sem in quam. Suspendisse sagittis ac enim in volutpat. Integer vel lectus quis sapien sollicitudin vehicula. Quisque id ligula tempus, molestie leo eget, sagittis dolor. Pellentesque tempor enim non elit condimentum commodo. In facilisis felis sed dapibus malesuada. Sed varius volutpat mi, id cursus neque consequat sed. ");
        t.setLineWrap(true);
        t.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        t.setEditable(false);   
        scroll.getViewport().add(t);
        return scroll;


     } 
private JLabel setPageDateLabel(){


    JLabel lblDate=new JLabel( );
    lblDate.setText("<html><table><tr><td style='width:10pt;'></td><td>Page 2 02/27/2015 10:40:13 AM</td></tr><tr><td style='width:10pt;'><img src='/src/Reader/QuestionMark.gif'></img></td><td>*Completed</td></tr></table></html>");
    //lblDate.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));     
    return lblDate;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
               // createAndShowGUI();
                new TestHTMLLabel();

            } 

              });

                }
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: I have checked and updated my answer and its working now. Try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String imgPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/Reader/QuestionMark.gif";
```

and after that add

```
lblDate.setText("<html><table><tr><td></td><td>Page 2 02/27/2015 10:40:13 AM</td></tr><tr><td><img src=file:'" + imgPath +"'></img></td><td>*Completed</td></tr></table></html>");
```

Notice the 'file:' after in src attribute

[image]

Comment: what is path of your java class?

Comment: Yep, I forget the "file" after in src attribute. It works. Thanks.